Exercise with multi-nucleon transfer reactions
For a practice exam, I received the following question:

"Your friend from nuclear theory predicted the production cross section for $^{265}\rm No$ and $^{267}$Lr in multi-nucleon transfer reactions. For the reaction $^{50}{\rm Ti} + ^{248}{\rm Cm}$ the
cross section of the production of No-265 is around 1.2 nb. You have a target of 0.5 mg/cm$^2$ thickness. The beam intensity of $^{50}$Ti is 4$\times$1012 ions/s. How much beam time will you need in order to get at least 1800 $^{267}$Lr atoms? $^{265}$No will be produced at the same time with a cross section of 0.38 μb. How many atoms of $^{265}$No will you produce?"

Now not only is it filled with small mistakes (i.e. I believe the first mentioned cross-section is actually for Lr-267), but this professor (which I dont hold in high regard) refuses to give a solutions manual for a PRACTICE EXAM
Anyways, I believe this can be solved using a simple formula from the lecture slides:

By first converting the 0.5mg/cm^2 to target nuclei using avogadro's number and the molar mass of Cm-248, I find $1.21\times 10^{18}$ target nuclei/cm^2.
Plug in all numbers into the formula, I get a low yield of 5.8E-3 Lr-267 created per second
Then by simply dividing 1800 by said yield gives a timeframe of nearly 310000 seconds
For the 2nd part of the question exchange the cross section in the same formula, follows a yield of 1.84 No-265 Nuclei per second. Similar method of 1800/1.84 = 978s of beam time.
As I have no reference frame whether this is a suitable method at all, I figured maybe you could help me out. Am I overlooking an easier way, or a more appropriate formula?

The practice question is really hard to follow. Do you think you could present it in a much simpler manner?

@JEB , I would, but sadly this is what I was given. My Nuclear Physics professor isn't quite the native speaker you'd hope a professor to be.
